# How to create multiple consecutive empty lines in Stack Exchange post

Tags: discussion

How do I create multiple consecutive empty lines in Stack Exchange post?

I have tried searching for this, and nothing seems to work in my post.

(Any advice on edits to this question are welcome.)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are getting at: is this in a code block or in the normal text?

Comment: We might want a copy of this question on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). When I left this comment, the question was on [tex.meta.stackexchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need *n* empty lines, then you can use the html-tag `<br />` *(n+1)* times—in the following example `<br />` is used 6 times which yields 5 empty lines:

```html
A<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />B
```

yields:

A
B

---

In markdown ending a line with a backslash means introducing a line-break:

```
A\⟨end of line⟩
\⟨end of line⟩
\⟨end of line⟩
\⟨end of line⟩
\⟨end of line⟩
\⟨end of line⟩
B
```

yields:

A





B

(*⟨end of line⟩* is the linefeed-character or carriage-return-character + linefeed-character.)

Answer (score 10):

You can cheat with `&nbsp;`:

test

test